# split string by char

Tags: string, scala, split

scala has a standard way of splitting a string in `StringOps.split`

it's behaviour somewhat surprised me though.

To demonstrate, using the quick convenience function

```
def sp(str: String) = str.split('.').toList
```

the following expressions all evaluate to true

```
(sp("") == List("")) //expected
(sp(".") == List()) //I would have expected List("", "")
(sp("a.b") == List("a", "b")) //expected
(sp(".b") == List("", "b")) //expected
(sp("a.") == List("a")) //I would have expected List("a", "")
(sp("..") == List()) // I would have expected List("", "", "")
(sp(".a.") == List("", "a")) // I would have expected List("", "a", "")
```

so I expected that split would return an array with (the number a separator occurrences) + 1 elements, but that's clearly not the case.

It is almost the above, but remove all trailing empty strings, but that's not true for splitting the empty string.

I'm failing to identify the pattern here. What rules does StringOps.split follow?

For bonus points, is there a good way (without too much copying/string appending) to get the split I'm expecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For curious you can find the code here.https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.scala

See the split function with the character as an argument(line 206).

I think, the general pattern going on over here is, all the trailing empty splits results are getting ignored.

Except for the first one, for which "if no separator char is found then  just send the whole string" logic is getting applied.

I am trying to find if there is any design documentation around these.

Also, if you use string instead of char for separator it will fall back to java regex split. As mentioned by @LRLucena, if you provide the limit parameter with a value more than size, you will get your trailing empty results. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Thank you, I just put in a documentation pull request.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` with a regular expression. I´m not sure, but I guess that the second parameter is the largest size of the resulting array.

```
def sp(str: String) = str.split("\\.", str.length+1).toList
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be consistent with these three rules:

1) Trailing empty substrings are dropped.

2) An empty substring is considered trailing before it is considered leading, if applicable.

3) First case, with no separators is an exception.

Comment: nulls? I certainly hope not.

Comment: Pardon my sloppy nomenclature.  I would say I was speaking generically, but then I would run afoul again.

Zero length strings.

Answer (score 0):

`split` follows the behaviour of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

That is split "around" the separator character, with the following exceptions:

- Regardless of anything else, splitting the empty string will always give `Array("")`
- Any trailing empty substrings are removed
- Surrogate characters only match if the matched character is not part of a surrogate pair.