# Convert scala string to key value pairs

Tags: scala, parsing

How to convert the string values to key-value pairs from the string format:

```
key1-value1,value2
```

to

```
(key1,value1),(key1,value2)?
```

Comment: It would help you get better and more comprehensive answer if you could provide more test cases and provide more detail for the question. Obviously, if this is the only case, you can get away with `answer=List(("key1","value1"),("key2","value2"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `.split("pattern")`.

```
val data = """key1-value1,value2"""

val kv = data.split("-") match {
  case Array(h, t) =>
    t.split(",").map(value => (h, value)).toList
}

println(kv)
```

output:

```
List((key1,value1), (key1,value2))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
scala> val a = "key1-value1,key2-value2,key3-value3"
a: String = key1-value1,key2-value2,key3-value3

scala> a.split(",").map( x=> { val y = x.split("-");(y(0),y(1)) } ).map( x=> (x._1,x._2) ).toMap
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2, key3 -> value3)

scala>
```

Comment: Re-read the question. This fails for the example string given by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Prayagupd is great and works just fine. This answer uses [scala's `split` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394875/2928853) which, unlike Java, allows an array of characters as input:

```
val data = """key1-value1,value2"""
val t = data.split(Array(',','-'))  //gives: Array(key1, value1, value2)
t.drop(1).map(i => (t.head, i))  //Create tuples using key1 and value[i]
```

which yields:

```
res0: Array[(String, String)] = Array((key1,value1), (key1,value2))
```

Comment: Why bother with an `Array[Char]` when you can just split on a character set? `split("[-,]")`

Comment: @jwvh, in this case, as I have commented on OP's question, none of this matters and all the answers are kind of an overkill for the stated problem. I was thinking maybe the OP has some other test cases and was trying to avoid any complexity that might arise from using regex, say something like `"['-,]"` which suddenly skips `-` character. But I agree that this answer might have been premature given the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.split(Array('-', ',')) match { 
  case Array(k, v1, v2) => List(k -> v1, k -> v2)
}
```

or

```
val r = """(.+)-(.+),(.+)""".r

data match {
  r(k, v1, v2) => List(k -> v1, k -> v2)
}
```

Comment: Be careful about using Regex when there is no clear criteria. Your regex will match something like `key1-value1-value2-value3,value4` which may or may not be what the OP intends.